# Prevent data deletion but allow adding and modifying in firebase realtime database?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I need to set up database rules to prevent certain sub-nodes from being accidentally deleted, but at the same time allow the sub-nodes to be added and modified. The node in question is `users/[userID]`. It's structured like this:

[image]

I don't want the data in `users/[userID]/soundcasts` to ever be deleted. And my current rules look like the following:

```
 "users": {
  ".read": true,
  ".indexOn": "stripe_id",
  "$userID": {        
    ".indexOn": "0",
    "soundcasts": {
      ".indexOn": "planID",  
      ".write": "newData.exists() && auth != null",
      "$soundcastID": {
         ".write": "newData.exists() && auth != null",
      } 
    },
  }  
},
```

This accomplishes what I want successfully, i.e. setting `users/[userID]/soundcasts` to `null` always fails. However, since there's no .write rule on the `users` node itself, I'm not able to add new users to the node :(

But if I set `".write": "newData.exists() && auth != null"` on the `users` node or the `users/[userID]` node, like so:

```
 "users": {
  ".read": true,
  ".indexOn": "stripe_id",
  "$userID": {        
    ".indexOn": "0",
    ".write": "newData.exists() && auth != null",
    "soundcasts": {
      ".indexOn": "planID",  
      ".write": "newData.exists() && auth != null",
      "$soundcastID": {
         ".write": "newData.exists() && auth != null",
      } 
    },
  }  
},
```

it becomes possible to set `users/[userID]/soundcasts` sub-node to `null`. I'm not sure why that happens.

I need to set up the rules so that I can add new users to `users` node, modify any of the sub-node data under `users/[userID]`, but prevent `users/[userID]/soundcasts` from being set to null.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

There's currently no way to set write rules to a node and another set of different rules to it's sub-node.

I would recommend creating a node `soundcasts` under the root node of your database to store these soundcasts, having the `userID` as key and have their soundcasts under each user. Then you'd be able to set your "no deletes" rule to this node:

```
"users": {
  ".read": true,
  ".indexOn": "stripe_id",
  "$userID": {
    ".write": true
  }  
},
"soundcasts":{
    ".indexOn":"planID",
    "$userID":{
        "$soundcastID": {
            ".write": "newData.exists() && auth != null",
        }
    }
}
```